# Calling multiple functions sequentially with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, loops, callback

I want to loop through an object that contains functions which will execute one after another. My most ideal approach would be to have these chain somehow (ie. `func2` waits for `func1` and `func3` waits for `func2`) but this needs to happen dynamically and the functions will all have different durations.

I'm using jQuery so I thought that perhaps "queue()" may help but I haven't worked with it much.

`A main concern` is to not add any scope/callbacks to the functions within the object. I'd rather somehow enclose them within a parent function to execute within the loop in order to create the callback/chaining.

Here's an example of what I've got now, but dumbed down. Thanks for any help!

```
var obj = [
{'name':'func1','callback':function(){ alert(1); }},
{'name':'func2','callback':function(){ alert(2); }},
{'name':'func3','callback':function(){ alert(3); }}
];

$.each(obj, function(x, el) { 
    el.callback();
});
```

Comment: I don't follow.  Is `obj` the correct input, or is it incorrectly structured?  What exactly is wrong with the above code (besides the 3 functions themselves being trivial)?

Comment: The problem is that the functions occur asynchronously instead of one after another. I also won't know how many functions are within the object so I don't want to/can't staticly chain them together.

Comment: No they don't.  In the above code, they are guaranteed to happen in order.

Comment: The code you have does exactly what you describe. func2 doesn't run until func1 returns, same with func3 and func2... How are you expecting it to work differently?

Comment: You are correct that they happen one after another but if I where to put more complex code into each function, perhaps relaying on animating the same elements on a page you'd see that the functions collide and you are best off to "chain" them or to make them wait for each other to finishing before firing. This is my problem. They aren't waiting to execute.

Comment: @clarke, the actual functions will execute in order.  However, any setTimeouts or async functions they start may not.  Thus, you need to use the appropriate callback options.  For instance, $.animate takes a callback as the third parameter.  It may help if you post a more realistic example.  However, if "not add any scope/callbacks to the functions" means the functions (func1, etc.) can't take a callback parameter, you may be out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var obj = [
     function() { alert(1); },
     function() { alert(2); },
     function() { alert(3); }
];
$.each(obj,function() {
    // Replace 500 with whatever you want
    setTimeout(this,500);
});
```

You can also use a `for` loop, since there is no reason to use `$.each`, although it's no problem:

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    // Replace 500 with whatever you want
    setTimeout(this[i],500);
}
```

It also depends on whether you want to have different timing based on what function you're executing.

Here is for a `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    // Replace 500 with whatever you want
    setTimeout(this[i],500 * i);
}
```

And with `$.each`:

```
$.each(obj,function(i) {
    // Replace 500 with whatever you want
    setTimeout(this,500 * i);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`async-waterfall`](https://github.com/es128/async-waterfall) library can also help you do this.